# Is there call overhead if std::bind is used in recursive way?

Tags: c++, functor, std-function, stdbind

I'm writing a template function which involved usage of `f = std::bind(std::bind(std::bind(...)))`.

but I'm not sure whether the c++ compiler is smart enough to unfold the calling chain.
What I mean is:

1. when creating functor `f`, is there multiple `std::bind()`
   invoked at runtime?
2. when calling `f()`, does it involves calling
   multiple `operator()` at different layers of bind_functor object.

As a simple example: Does `f2()` run slightly faster than `f1()`?

```
#include <functional>

int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int main() {
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  auto f1 = std::bind(std::bind(&add, 1, _1), 2);
  auto f2 = std::bind(&add, 1, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
I did some experiment. It seems `f2()` does run faster than `f1()`. And if you use `std::function`, it is even slower. Here is the experimental code (ubuntu/gcc 7.5.0, with optimization enabled. Without optimization, `f2` is the slowest.). On my computer, the output is:

```
f1: 16851813
f2: 17567904
f3: 30655284
```

Here is the code (updated according to the comment of Nate):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int add(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

int main() {
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  auto f1 = std::bind(std::bind(&add, 1, _1, _2), 2, _1);
  auto f2 = std::bind(&add, 1, 2, _1);
  std::function<int(int)> f3 = std::bind(&add, 1, 2, _1);
  const int N = 10000000;
  volatile int x = 0;

  {
    auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
      x = f1(x);
    }   
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto d = end - begin;
    std::cout << "f1: " << d.count() << std::endl;
  }

  x = 0;
  {
    auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
      x = f2(x);
    }   
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto d = end - begin;
    std::cout << "f2: " << d.count() << std::endl;
  }

  x = 0;
  {
    auto begin = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
      x = f3(x);
    }   
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto d = end - begin;
    std::cout << "f3: " << d.count() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For g++ 10.2, your test results are explained by the fact that gcc notices that `f1()` and `f2()` have no side effects and their return values are unused, so they can therefore be optimized out.  Thus your test is measuring the time taken to execute nothing at all.  https://godbolt.org/z/TM61b7, note that each of the first two tests just compile into back-to-back calls to `now()`, with no loop or anything else in between.  I don't think that's what you wanted to measure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Nate. I have change the code, so that the return value of f1() f2() and f3() will all be used.  But I still got the similar result, that is: in term of used loop time, f2 < f1 < f3

Comment: I tried to use godbolt.org. It is a very good tool. I need to know assembly better to understand to compiled code.

Comment: In Visual C++ 2019 compiling for x64 with -O2, I observe that both `f1` and `f2` are inlined into a simple add, whereas `f3` is a call to the functor implementation.  The difference is explained by inlining heuristics in the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas `std::function` uses type-erasure and so should do code equivalent to virtual call for `operator()`, `bind`'s result can know real types and use static calls (which are simpler to inline by compiler).

Nested `bind` would do extra static calls, but probably inlined so might give same code.

[Quickbench Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/FdKo4_00ph8zWL-hg3puj8xxM0U) confirms that for your example:

Same timing for nested or not nested `bind`, but `std::function` slower.